# ACF: Obtaining info in vars from nested group

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have the following field setup:

```html
welcome_screen (type: group)
  title
  terms_group (type: group)
    terms_text (type: text)
```

I'm trying to get the value of `terms_text`.

Here's what I have so far:

```html
<?php
$welcome_screen = get_field('welcome_screen'); // type: group

if($welcome_screen):
  $title        = $welcome_screen['title'];

  while( have_rows('welcome_screen') ): the_row();
    $terms_group = $welcome_screen('terms_group'); // nested group
    $terms_text           = $terms_group['terms_text'];
  endwhile;

endif;

echo $terms_text;

?>
```

Currently, if I `echo $terms_text` in the `while` loop, I get the error `Function name must be a string` on this line: `$terms_group = $welcome_screen('terms_group');`

I'm also want to use the `$terms_text` variable outside the loop, so wondering if there's an alternate way to achieve what I want without a while loop?

**EDIT:**

I have ran a `var_dump` to check the output:

```html
$welcome_screen = get_field('welcome_screen'); // type: group
echo '<pre>'; var_dump($welcome_screen); echo '</pre>';
```

Here is the output:

```html
array(3) {
  ["title"]=>
  string(13) "Health Survey"
  ["standfirst"]=>
  string(113) "We just need some answers to some quick health questions about your general health to get you the best treatment."
  ["terms_group"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["terms_text"]=>
    string(41) "By proceeding you agree to the following:"
    ["terms_listing"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["terms"]=>
        string(88) ""
      }
      [1]=>
      array(1) {
        ["terms"]=>
        string(0) ""
      }
    }
    ["agree_to_terms_radio"]=>
    string(3) "Yes"
  }
}
```

Comment: Immediately after `$welcome_screen = get_field('welcome_screen');` can you add `echo '<pre>'; var_dump($welcome_screen); echo '</pre>';` and share the outputted dump array please.

Comment: Hi @joshmoto - Sure :) I've edited my question to showcase the output

Comment: why not just loop normally through the array?

Comment: If you are trying to get the `$terms_text` outside of the `while` loop, there seems to be no reason to even use a loop here. Why not use the array keys for direct access to the data? It appears you aren't even using the loop to iterate over multiple arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok cool cheers for posting the dump data.

So I don't think need you use loops, you could try this php below. It is not tested so you might need to fix any errors if I've made any.

I can't remember if acf outputs array values if they are not set, so you might need to add `isset()` to some of the php vars to check if is set.

See comments in code...

```php
<?php

// get welcome screen group
$welcome_screen = get_field('welcome_screen');

// check if we have group
if($welcome_screen) {
  
  // output the welcome title
  echo $welcome_screen['title'];
  
  // set the terms group
  $terms_group = $welcome_screen['terms_group'];

  // if terms group is array
  if(is_array[$terms_group]) {
    
    // output term group term text
    echo $terms_group['terms_text'];

    // set term group term listing
    $terms_listings = $terms_group['terms_listing'];
    
    // if terms listings is an array
    if(is_array($terms_listings)) {
      
      // foreach listings
      foreach($terms_listings as $terms_listing) {
        
        // output listing terms
        echo $terms_listing['terms'];

      }

    }

    // output term group term agreement
    echo $terms_group['agree_to_terms_radio'];

  }

}
```